# how to do a pbuilder-dist build with dependencies in a ppa?

Tags: ppa, packaging, pbuilder-dist

I'm trying to build a package for my ppa that uses packages from two other ppas. I want to do a test build using `pbuilder-dist`. I have done this before and I know that I need a combination of:

- `OTHERMIRROR` in `~/.pbuilderrc`
- `--override-config`, but I'm not sure when to add it to the `pbuilder-dist` call
- `pbuilder-dist raring update` and `pbuilder-dist raring build <pkg>.dsc`
- maybe other things?

Can someone give a detailed description? I have tried different combinations, but nothing seems to work.

The two ppas I need are `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` and `ppa:tkluck/gnome3`. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm using pbuilder with an enhanced config and not pbuilder-dist but the steps should be basically the same:

1. Add your extra sources to the `OTHERMIRROR` variable in your `~/.pbuilderrc`:

   ```
   OTHERMIRROR="deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu raring main|deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tkluck/gnome3/ubuntu raring main"
   ```
2. Chroot into your pbuilder environment to add the repository keys (or alternatively create a local keyring with those two keys and add it to `APTKEYSTRINGS` variable or add your local `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` keyring):

   ```
   pbuilder-dist raring login --save-after-login
   apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 3B1510FD 568F2AD3
   exit
   ```

   (Of course you can extend your sources.list directly and skip step 1 and 3 but an `pbuilder-dist update` will reset the sources.list.)
3. Update your pbuilder environment (with plain pbuilder you have to add `--override-config`):

   ```
   pbuilder-dist raring update --release-only
   ```

   Note: Since raring a development release has the `proposed` sources enabled as default. This is done by passing the `proposed` sources to pbuilder's `--othermirror` command line option - which overwrites the config file value. So you have to use the `--release-only` switch.
4. Build your package:

   ```
   pbuilder-dist raring build YOURPACKAGE.dsc
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It doesn't seem to work for me, however. Any changes I make during a `pbuilder-dist raring login` session are discarded. According to the documentation in `pbuilder`, that's normal behaviour.

Comment: Also, even without importing the keys, I would expect the `update` step to complain for missing keys for some sources. It doesn't, so it seems to completely ignore the `OTHERMIRROR` variable.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the important `--save-after-login`. Now it will work with a plain `~/.pbuilderrc` (I have checked it myself).

Comment: This works for me if, inside the `login --save-after-login` session, I add the `deb` line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and call `apt-get update`. It seems to fail with just `pbuilder-dist raring update`, and I'm not sure if I can call it again or that it will just overwrite what I had just accomplished. Maybe you can explain and update your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work. Is there any other content in your `~/.pbuilderrc` or did you misspelled this file? I will update the answer that an update will reset the sources.list.

Comment: Here's my `~/.pbuilderrc` file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5607994/ It looks good to me, no spelling errors, right?

Comment: It does work very well with your config. Please show some debug output: `pbuilder-dist raring update --debug-echo`

Comment: Here's the debug output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5618176/ Maybe the raring-proposed that's passed as an `--other-mirror` flag overrides the one in `.pbuilderrc`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the problem, I will update the answer.

Comment: thanks! i'm awarding you the bounty now because it ends soon. I will accept your answer after testing it.

Comment: @TimoKluck: Have you tested it yet?

Comment: Sorry Lasall, I have been working on other things for a while. This seems very complete so I'll just accept the answer. If I run into any troubles while testing, I'll update the answer with any extra steps I need.

Answer (score 5):

You can also create a `Dsomething` file stating the repository you want to add. If you have `HOOKDIR="${HOME}/.pbuilder-hooks/"` in your `~/.pbuilderrc`, then a file called `$HOME/.pbuilder-hooks/D10addppa` could exist with the following content:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "deb deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu raring main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tkluck/gnome3/ubuntu raring main"  >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B1510FD 568F2AD3
apt-get update
```

This method also keeps the PPA changes temporal.