# Force PPA package to satisfy distro meta-package dependency

Tags: apt, packaging, metapackages, pbuilder-dist

I am building a package for my ppa that requires a newer implementation of libboost than what is provided in my target distro (precise). I've copied libboost1.55 from the [boost ppa](https://launchpad.net/~boost-latest/+archive/ppa) into my ppa.  I'm using pbuilder-dist to test my package build. I have successfully used the answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265703/how-to-do-a-pbuilder-dist-build-with-dependencies-in-a-ppa) question to get pbuilder to get libboost packages from the ppa into the chroot environment.

Unfortunately, while all the dependencies can be installed from the ppa as `libboost-libname1.55-dev`, none of them satisfy the meta package `libboost-libname-dev` and the `pbuilder-dist` build fails due to unsatisfied dependencies.

So, this question is not necessarily only tied to `pbuilder-dist`, but how would I either let pbuilder ignore the packages for dependencies (as I'm sure the dependency is met), or make apt-get consider the meta package dependency satisfied? I would prefer not to mess with the `debian/control` unless there is no other way.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this? There isn't any package named `libboost-libname-dev` in Trusty (or [any release](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libboost-libname-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), it seems). EDIT: never mind; I failed to realize that the name part should be replaced by the module name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the main metapackage that is updated to depend on Boost 1.55 libraries isn't supplied through the PPA, you get the dependency errors. No builder (`pbuilder` or `sbuild`) or package manager (`apt-get`) will allow building/installing a package where the dependencies aren't met, as this indicates that the package will fail to build or work. Therefore, you will have to go into `debian/control`. To get around the error, try using dependency alternatives to specify using either the main metapackage if it is of a sufficient version or the alternative version.

To do this, in the case of a Boost module called *name*, the dependency for that module would look like `libboost-name-dev (>= 1.55.0) | libboost-name1.55-dev`. In this case, the `libboost-name-dev` will be used if it is at least version 1.55; otherwise, it will use `libboost-name1.55-dev`.

Note that you may need to manually enable using alternatives in `pbuilder`.